# How to create a custom C++ range/view?

Tags: c++, view, range

I am creating a compiler (PoC) in C++ and I wanted to use range library for my use case. For the lexer phase, this is the type of "transformation" that I would like to have:

Input: `string_view`.

Output: A view of tokens, just like `iota` is used for integers, but with finite amount of Tokens to be generated. Also, the type of iteration on this is like Input Iterator, as the tokens are generated in real time, and the state is managed internally by the lexer.

I have implemented the Lexer and the following code works:

```
...
static auto read_file(string_view filename)
{
    ifstream file{ filename.data() };
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << file.rdbuf(); // reading data
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    auto dfa = fetch_dfa();
    auto str = read_file("source.jack");

    auto token_stream = Lexer(dfa, str);
    for (auto x : token_stream)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

I want to use the `token_stream` and pipe it to the Parser (which is not implemented yet, but that's irrelevant for now). But I am unable to find anything which I can use to achieve this. Can someone help me here? I want to implement something like `std::iota` but for my Tokens (instead of integers).

I don't mind writing my own view class from scratch for the stream of `Tokens`, as long as my custom view works with standard library, as I am also learning how ranges work under the hood.

**Update:** Here is the code which I tried to implement but got the error that there is no suitable conversion for pipe operator:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Iterator
{
public:
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = int;
    using difference_type = int;
    using pointer = const int*;
    using reference = const int&;

    Iterator(int value) : m_value{ value } {}

    reference operator*() const { return m_value; }
    pointer operator->() const { return &m_value; }

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++m_value;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int)
    {
        Iterator tmp{ *this };
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b)
    {
        return a.m_value == b.m_value;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};

class MyView : public std::ranges::view_interface<MyView>
{
public:
    auto begin() const { return Iterator(0); }

    auto end() const { return Iterator(10); }
};

int main()
{
    MyView view_over_v;
    for (int n : view_over_v | std::views::take(2))
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This is the error I received:

```
error C2678: binary '|': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'MyView' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\cstddef(48,39):
1>could be 'std::byte std::operator |(const std::byte,const std::byte) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ranges(181,35):
1>or       'auto std::ranges::_Pipe::operator |(_Left &&,_Right &&) noexcept(<expr>)'
...
1>  the associated constraints are not satisfied
1>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ranges(178,22):
1>      the concept 'std::ranges::_Pipe::_Range_adaptor_closure_object<MyView&>' evaluated to false
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ranges(124,57):
1>          'std::ranges::_Pipe::_Derived_from_range_adaptor_closure': no matching overloaded function found
1>              C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ranges(119,14):
1>              could be '_Ty *std::ranges::_Pipe::_Derived_from_range_adaptor_closure(std::ranges::_Pipe::_Base<_Derived> &)'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ranges(188,35):
1>or       'auto std::ranges::_Pipe::operator |(_Left &&,_Right &&) noexcept(<expr>)'
...
1>  the associated constraints are not satisfied
1>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ranges(187,64):
1>      the concept 'std::ranges::range<MyView&>' evaluated to false
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(2469,20):
1>          call to object of class type 'std::ranges::_End::_Cpo': no matching call operator found
1>              C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(2445,39):
1>              could be 'auto std::ranges::_End::_Cpo::operator ()(_Ty &&) noexcept(<expr>) const'
```

Comment: [`std::ranges::view_interface`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) is a good place to start.  Or you can start from scratch and build a class that fulfils the [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) or [`std::ranges::view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) concepts.

Comment: Hi, I tried this earlier too, but was unable to compile the code. I attached a minimal code in the post, which failed to compile and I am stuck here

Comment: The iterator type returned by `end` needs to be default-constructable.  Specifically, it needs to model [`std::sentinel_for<std::ranges::iterator_t<MyView>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sentinel_for) and one of the requirements for that is that it's default-constructable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I have a Lexer which generates tokens. For the input side, I would like to have something like this:
`"...."sv | Lexer(dfa)`.
Do you have idea on how to support pipe operator and the signature of Lexer's constructor? I know I can override the `|` operator, but I am wondering if there is a way that will be "good" as per `std::views` semantics

Comment: You essentially can't prior to C++23, which introduced [`std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range_adaptor_closure).